How do I restore deleted files from rsync?
I used the following command
rsync -avh --progress --remove-source-files --delete /mnt/disk-1/* /mnt/disk-2

I thought that delete would overwrite files in my destination directory. But instead, it deleted the files in the destination directory if they didn't exist.
I tried restoring files with ext4magic, extundelete, testdisk and had no luck.
ext4magic, tries to restore the files but I get segmentation fault and stops...
Both filesystems are ext4
Any programs I could try?

Does this answer your question? How to recover deleted files?
